# SQL query to delete multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How we can delete multiple rows having columns from a db?
Suppose db has following data (id, list_name, user) and list_name has values as:

```
 Owner-aaa
 coowner-aaa
 owner-aaa
 subowner-aaa
```

How we can delete the rows having "Owner-aaa" and "owner-aaa" which are duplicates?

Can we add something in this query here:

```
delete from <table_name> where list_name = 'owner-aaa'
```

But it deletes only lower case list, I want something general which checks duplicates in small and caps and delete both of them?

Thanks in advance
Amy

Comment: you want to delete both Owner-aaa and owner-aaa, or you want to keep just one and delete all of the others?

Comment: or do you want to delete all duplicated rows??

Comment: I wanted to delete all rows... -Amy

Comment: Another alternative:  change to a case-insensitive collation, and your original DELETE statement would work just fine...     It would also allow you to use some of the query strategies defined in the answers without having to use UPPER() or LOWER(), which means that indexes could be used directly in the query, leading to vastly faster performance (especially if your table has many rows).

Comment: @Curt Thanks, I was trying with like I am not sure how syntax should be. Can you help me with the query too, if possible.

Comment: Sure:  post your table schema and use case, or some contact info so we can do this offline (Skype / Google Chat ID, or email adddress).

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from tableName where LOWER(list_name) = 'owner-aaa'
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, OP said nothing about keeping rows, just to delete rows no matter if values are upper or lower case.

Comment: OP said they want something general, this has a hard-coded value in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(listname) IN
(SELECT LOWER(listname) FROM mytable 
GROUP BY LOWER(listname)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: mysql usually ignores case when grouping, but doesn't allow you do use an IN clause in a delete query

Comment: That would work, but would remove all records for which a duplicate exists (i.e., it would not leave one)

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure about MySQL, and yes, it removes all dupes, which is how I interpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE a
FROM list a
INNER JOIN list b ON LOWER(a.list_name)=LOWER(b.list_name)
WHERE a.id <> b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Meaby you can use LOWER/UPPER sql functions.

But are you sure your model is correct? It seem realy weird to have a name list like that. That should be another table NAMES with ID and NAME field. It's a 1-N relation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from your question whether you want to delete all rows where duplicates occur, or leave one, and remove only the true duplicates.    So here's a shot at each:

To remove only the true duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE id IN
(
   SELECT T1.id 
     FROM MyTable T1
          INNER JOIN MyTable T2
             ON UPPER(T1.list_name) = UPPER(T2.list_name)
            AND T2.id <> T1.id
            AND (T1.id <> (SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable WHERE UPPER(list_name) = UPPER(T1.list_name))
) DUPS
```

This presumes that the id field is unique to each record

To remove *all* records where there are duplicates, remove the two "AND" clauses in the subquery.

Comment: I want to delete all rows eg. owner-aaa and Owner-aaa both irrespective of the total no count.